# temporal smoothing: FWHM of Gaussian kernel vs. window length of moving average

Tags: smoothing, moving-average, gaussian-kernel

Suppose in one case I convolve Gaussian kernel with FWHM=10 samples. I would like to compare the result with moving average. My question: should I take the moving average window also 10 samples? In other words, is the size of FWHM equivalent to window of moving average?

Thanks!

Comment: equivalent by what criteria ?

Comment: Sorry,equivalent might not be a precise word. I mean that if let's say I want to compare the two methods, should I take FWHM and window length the same?